# useFocusEffect() from react navigation not calling my API always

Tags: api, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I need your help to find a workaround or something to fix this issue.

I have some providers and category names in my DB that I need to gather to display them in a Picker inside a AddProduct Screen that my app has, however most of the times when I just open the app an go to my AddProduct Screen those Picker components are not displayed. In order to fix it I need to go to my Home Screen (or any other of my screens) and then go back to my AddProduct Screen, in that way my provider and categories are displayed. I tried to use the useFocusEffect() from react navigation 5.x to call my API and download the information, I thought that maybe using the 'focus' eventListener I was going to fix the issue, but it did no happen, so my code is the following, Im pretty sure that I don't have any error there but maybe you guys have experimented the same issue and can help me to fix it or find a workaround.

Below the useEffect code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', async () => {
    const userDetails = await getUserDetails('@user_details');
    const categories = await readAllCategories(userDetails.jwt, userDetails.secretKey, userDetails.storeId);
    setActiveCategories(categories.categories);
    const branches = await readAllBranches(userDetails.jwt, userDetails.secretKey, userDetails.storeId);
    setActiveBranches(branches.branches);
    const providers = await readAllProviders(userDetails.jwt, userDetails.secretKey, userDetails.storeId);
    setActiveProviders(providers.providers);
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
  setIsLoading(true);
  setActiveCategories(true);
  (async () => {
    const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    const { granted } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if(status && granted){
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    }
    setCameraVisible(false);
    const userDetails = await getUserDetails('@user_details');
    setUserDetailsData({
      jwt: userDetails.jwt,
      secretKey: userDetails.secretKey,
      storeId: userDetails.storeId,
      emailAddress: userDetails.emailAddress
    })
    const categories = await readAllCategories(userDetails.jwt, userDetails.secretKey, userDetails.storeId);
    const branches = await readAllBranches(userDetails.jwt, userDetails.secretKey, userDetails.storeId);
    const providers = await readAllProviders(userDetails.jwt, userDetails.secretKey, userDetails.storeId);
    setActiveCategories(categories.categories);
    setActiveBranches(branches.branches);
    setActiveProviders(providers.providers);
    setIsLoading(false);
  })();
  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

and below the code that I have to render my Pickers, Im adding only the one for Providers as exmaple:

```
{activeProviders === undefined ? (null) : (
  <View style={{width: '90%', height: 40, borderColor: '#D6D6D6', borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5, paddingLeft: 5, marginTop: 10}}>
    <Picker
      selectedValue={productInformation.provider}
      style={{height: 40}}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => handleProductInformation({provider: itemValue})}
      itemTextStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 20}}
    >
      < Picker.Item color='#CFCFCF' label='Seleccionar Proveedor' value={0} key={0} />
      {activeProviders.map((item, index) => {
        return (< Picker.Item color={black} label={item.name} value={item.id} key={index} />);
      })}   
    </Picker> 
  </View>
)}
```

and finally the function that gets the data from my API:

```
/*****     GET ALL PROVIDERS     *****/
export const readAllProviders = async (jwt, sweetSugar, storeId) =>{
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://myurl.com/endPoints/getProviders.php',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'jwt ' + jwt,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }), 
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sweetSugar: sweetSugar, 
        storeId: storeId
      })
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
  }catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```